# EPPlus: Cell displayed '-125,949.00' but return '-125949'

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPlus to read excel data using c#. Excel contains data like below.

Amt
-125,949.00
-909,123.21

I am trying to read the exact data in variable using below mentioned code, but it's not returning the exact value including ',' and '.00'. If value is '-125,949.00' then its returning '-125949'. If value is '-909,123.21' then is returning '-909123.21'.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileStr))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
        var amt = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value;
    }
}
```

So how do I actually get the exact value including ',' and '.00' and save it in variable?

I tried searching online and tried converting to double or decimal, but I got same result.

I tried using .Text but its returning '0'.

```
var amt = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Text
```

The reason I want exact value is I need to perform some validations later. e.g. If Amt is other than Decimal, then I need to show some error message. As I am getting -125949 in variable, so I am not able to perform the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols like `,` and `.` are formatting elements - 1000<sup>th</sup> and decimal separators accordingly. The numbers `-125,949.00` and `-909,123.21` usually are saved as numbers. Therefore, to see in `amt` what you are expecting it's necessary to convert these numbers to string using formatter:

```cs
var amt = ((double)worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value).ToString("#,0.00");
```

Now you will see what you are expecting.

Comment: I tried this way, its working as expected, many thanks :)

Comment: This will fail (InvalidCastException) when the value is not a `double`. Plus this converts `amt` to a string, which is not the best type to work with numerical values

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: In the description above is noted that this code for case when values **are saved as number** in the excel worksheet.

Comment: True, but in a comment to another answer the OP specified adding "validations for non-decimal values"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `-125,949.00` and `-125949` *are* exactly the same values, it's just that the former has some extra decorations on it.
The *only* purpose of those decorations is to make the value look pretty to *human* eyes, it has no purpose whatsoever for anything else, including storing it in a variable.

If you want to make your numbers look pretty, you can change the numerical value that you have to a `string` using a *format* of your choice.
One way to do that is to use [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0).

Keep in mind that you *only* want to do that to show the value in a pretty way to *human* eyes. You can no longer calculate things with it after you turn it into a string, and you most probably do not want to store it in a database as a string!

Comment: The reason I want exact value is I need to perform some validations later. e.g. If Amt is other than Decimal, then I need to show some error message. As I am getting -125949 in variable, so I am not able to perform the validation.

Comment: Your `amt` probably has compile type type `object`. But the runtime type may be `double` (or maybe `decimal` - please check using the `is` operator), which you want, or `string` which you want to show an error for

Answer (score 0):

Excel interprets integers with decimal places and 'dot' notations based on the column's format style, rather than the actual values stored in the cells. To address this, you can implement a custom function within your program that adjusts the numeric values according to your specific needs.